# Javascript Affecting Image Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image and a line of text on top of a blue box, all fading in with JavaScript. If I don't use any JS, I can center the image without any problems. But as soon as the JS is used, the image does not center anymore. However, the line of text does. Why does this happen?

Here are the code samples:

```js
$("#box").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 5500
});

$("#txt").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 10500
});

$("#pic").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 10500
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cultura.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div id="box">

    <img id="pic" src="pic.jpg">

    <p id="txt"> a line of text </p>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cultura.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `cultura.css` or `cultura.js` required for this sample? Make sure to include only what's required to show the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have approved a suggested edit.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity is setting your element's CSS `display` property to `inline`. Explicitly specify the `fadeIn` should set the `display` to `block` on your `#img` element:

```js
$("#box").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 5500
});

$("#txt").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 10500
});

$("#pic").velocity("fadeIn", {
  duration: 10500,
  display: "block"
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cultura.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div id="box">

    <img id="pic" src="pic.jpg">

    <p id="txt"> a line of text </p>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cultura.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```